# Using PowerShell to get info from AzureAD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get all users info,

But I want to filter by dynamic groups, is it possible?

right now Im just using this
`Get-AzureADUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment, and I got the list of **dynamic group members** successfully

You can also see the list of current group members via the Azure portal, or use the following PowerShell command :

```
(Get-AzureADGroup -ALL $true -Filter "DisplayName eq 'YourGroupName'" | Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL $true )
```

[image]